# custom data sorting(alphabetic+integer) in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have a dataframe where I need to sort the contents of one column (comma separated) (alphabetically + Numberic) :

Input : -

```
      Invoice Number
0     IN-2
1     IN-1
2     IN-5
3     IN-20
4     IN-10
```

I want output like

```
      Invoice Number
0     IN-1
1     IN-2
2     IN-5
3     IN-10
4     IN-20
```

I tried

> df.sort_values(by=['Invoice Number'])

But it sorted :

```
      Invoice Number
0     IN-1
1     IN-10
2     IN-2
3     IN-20
4     IN-5
```

If anybody know how to sort my data (alphabetic+integer) value so tell me.

Comment: In your case pandas is sorting by each single character in your column. An option would be to seperate the string '"IN-"' from the number in a new column and then sort the column with the numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`natsort`](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/) is helpful in these situations:

```
import pandas as pd
from natsort import natsort_key

df = pd.DataFrame({'Invoice': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4},
                   'Number': {0: 'IN-2', 1: 'IN-1', 2: 'IN-5', 3: 'IN-20',
                              4: 'IN-10'}})

df = df.sort_values('Number', key=natsort_key)
```

`df`:

```
   Invoice Number
1        1   IN-1
0        0   IN-2
2        2   IN-5
4        4  IN-10
3        3  IN-20
```

---

A more interesting example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Invoice': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4},
                   'Number': {0: 'RHKW-11', 1: 'AB-1', 2: 'IN-5', 3: 'IN-20',
                              4: 'RHKW-102'}})
```

`df`:

```
   Invoice    Number
0        0   RHKW-11
1        1      AB-1
2        2      IN-5
3        3     IN-20
4        4  RHKW-102
```

`df = df.sort_values('Number', key=natsort_key)`:

```
   Invoice    Number
1        1      AB-1
2        2      IN-5
3        3     IN-20
0        0   RHKW-11
4        4  RHKW-102
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with a place holder column:

```
df['_'] = df['Invoice Number'].str.split('-').str[1].astype(int)
print(df.sort_values('_').drop('_', axis=1).reset_index(drop=True))
```

Or with the `key` argument:

```
print(df.sort_values('Invoice Number', key=lambda x: x.str.split('-').str[1].astype(int))
```

Both codes output:

```
  Invoice Number
0           IN-1
1           IN-2
2           IN-5
3          IN-10
4          IN-20
```

Comment: `lambda x: int(x.str[3:])` won't work as `x.str[3:]` is a Series, not a scalar.

Comment: @mozway I used `split` now, so different from your code, check it out

Comment: I was about to add the split variant ;)

Comment: You can maybe comment on the fact that the split variant will work even if the part before "-" is variable

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the `key` option of [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df.sort_values(by='Number', key=lambda x: x.str[3:].astype(int))
```

What it does is to get rid of the "IN-" part and convert to int.

Comment: All rows not has IN-xxx  it maybe RHKW-xxx or AMH-xxx  anything in alphabet.